# Is there anyway to integrate facebook into a Unity desktop application?

Tags: macos, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Unity's cross-platform application (Win, macOS, Android, iOs) and I wanted to include a facebook login so users could sign up via Facebook. I've already been able to do it in Android and iOS platforms through the following link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted

This method doesn't work for standalone desktop platforms. I've been looking for a solution to the problem, but I haven't found anything.

Does anyone know a solution or a plugin for Unity that can include Facebook Login for Desktop Standalone platforms?

Comment: Did you google? Simple google search, and this was the first result:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear. I've already edited the question.

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly isn't working in the Desktop build, and what (if any) errors you receive.

Comment: It just doesn't work. It's not a error. Facebook doesn't support desktop platforms. When we try to perform the same tasks on the desktop, the Facebook login window doesn't appear. There has to be another way to log in to Facebook from Desktop Unity App. Usually, what conventional applications do is open the browser and, from the login made there, go back to the program. But I would like to find a simpler solution.

Comment: @BrandonMiller There is no support for standalone builds at all (!)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook still does not have any way to use its official SDK in Standalone builds (it's 2019 now, and posts requesting that feature can be seen dated as far as 2013...)

The options (as of now) are:

## 1. Manually build Facebook login flow

(that *requires* server-side support and opening a webpage outside of Unity) - see here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

**Pros:**

- Cheapest option if you can self-host executables
- Good start option
- Some major gamedev companies went for such solution (even Blizzard!)

**Cons:**

- You will need to minimalize Unity game to log-in
- Requires some time to code and test properly

**Note:**

- Tested in one of my own games;

## 2. Use third-party provider

(like [Google's Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/))

**Pros:**

- You have it up and running in matter of minutes
- You can integrate other login methods

**Cons:**

- You are locked in with that provider
- It costs you on per-user base

**Note:**

- Also tested in some other of my games;
- There are several urban legends that Firebase is way more costly then it promises; See [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d) (*"How we spent 30k USD in Firebase in less than 72 hours"*) and [here](https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb) (*"Unexpected monthly bill of more than 1.000€"*)

## 3. Embed Chromium directly into Unity, use in-browser authentication

You will need either free and open software chromium framework ([here](https://bitbucket.org/vitaly_chashin/simpleunitybrowser/downloads/) or [here](https://github.com/aleab/cef-unity-sample)), or if you need premium support - [this plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/embedded-browser-55459).
Then you must follow this tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/
But this time - using embedded browser, which does not requires external server.

**Pros:**

- No recurring paymants
- Does not take your users away from your game

**Cons:**

- This is treated as new browser for user; Cookies, stored session, etc. will not be available
- *Let me stress that out again*: users will have to explicitly login to Facebook, without their favorite password managers
- Still need some time to code and test propertly

**Note:**

- I did **NOT** throughtly tested that. Use at your own risk - I would actually recomend either 1. or 2.

Comment: Hi @PiotrK in option 2 I think you suggest Firebase lets users login via Facebook into a unity macos app. Still today there is no FB SDK for macos a the op says. Can you please point where you see Firebase SDK allows users login via FB into a unity macos built app? or as you tested it in your games can you please elaborate how? thanks a bunch

Comment: @SergioSolorzano There is no SDK for Unity - you have to integrate Firebase yourself. Here is a good info about that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup